# When does Salesforce lock lookup?

Tags: salesforce

I have an object 'Ben' in Salesforce that has an Account lookup. I want to do a Bulk API Update on the 'Ben' object to around 3.5 million records using Informatica Cloud. The update only modifies 3 other fields which have no lookup.There is no update to the Account Id.Will Salesforce lock the Account record in this case?